# Excel insert selected range

Tags: microsoft-excel, range, list

I have a cell A1 with list (GROUP 1, GROUP 2, GROUP 3) and 3 groups of names (E1:G7).

I would like to select for example GROUP 3 and it would then printout all names in that group in cells C2:C7.

Is it possible with basic excel formulas not with macros?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the new Dynamic Array Formulas you can use:

```
=FILTER(E2:G7,E1:G1=A1)
```

Put that in C2 and the rest will fill down automatically.

If not then use INDEX(,,MATCH).   Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(E:G,ROW(E2),MATCH($A$1,$E$1:$G$1,0))
```

Both formula will return `0` for blank, so format the cells with a custom number format of `;;;@`  To make them appear blank.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for!
Thank You!